# React - making a style object globally accessible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a basic color picker app to learn React and possess a better understanding of it.

The way this works is I have a text field which accepts hex values, and displays them as a background color as you type. What I want to have happen is have the background go back to none as a default when you clear the text field. Right now, it reverts to the previous color that was typed in. The functional code I have so far is as follows:

```
class ColorPick extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: "Let's pick a color"
    };
  }

  changeColor(event) {
    var colorInput = document.getElementById('colorInput').value;
    this.setState({
      color: event.target.value
    });
    if (colorInput === '') {
      this.setState({
       color: "Let's pick a color",
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
      });
   }
  }

  render () {
    var styleObj = {
      backgroundColor: this.state.color,
    };

    return (
      <section style={styleObj} id="Profile" >
        <h2 className="colorHeader">{this.state.color}</h2> 
        <input id="colorInput" placeholder="Enter Hex Code Here"     onChange={this.changeColor.bind(this)}/>
      </section>
    );
 }
   }

ReactDOM.render(<ColorPick />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

To achieve the clearing on the colored background with an empty text field, I'm attempting to globalize the variable/object `styleObj` and change it's value to have `backgroundColor: none` if the value of the field is blank. along with that, I'm declaring it using `let`. So to do that I tried:

```
class ColorPick extends React.Component {
  // making styleObj global and changing from var to let.
  let styleObj = {
    backgroundColor: this.state.color,
  };
```

...

```
changeColor(event) {
    var colorInput = document.getElementById('colorInput').value;
    this.setState({
      color: event.target.value
    });
    if (colorInput === '') {
      this.setState({
        color: "Let's pick a color",
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
      });
      // attempting to reset back to default after text field is cleared
      let styleObj = {
        backgroundColor: none,
      };
    }
  }
```

However, two unexpected results happened:

1. The component completely disappeared from the page after making `styleObj` a global object variable
2. `backgroundColor` becomes an unexpected identifier.

Shouldn't making that CSS block a global variable/object be accessible to the entire scope? I've also tried changing the specific placement of my variable, ranging from right beneath the component creation to right above the `render` method. Should I be doing this a different way?

Below are two forks, the functional version, and the version that doesn't work with comments:

working version:
https://codepen.io/kawnah/pen/EZqLaq?editors=0010

non-working version:
https://codepen.io/kawnah/pen/XpvOpp?editors=0010

EDIT: As you can see, For my placeholder for my color state I'm using a string. Expecting that to break, it worked. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only using `this.state.color` in your `render()` function. This means that when the box is empty, you're trying to set the CSS `background-color` to `"Let's pick a color"`.

You also *only* set `this.state.color` to respond to the change event.
But then when you go to reset it (when `colorInput === ''`), you set `this.state.color` *AND* `this.state.backgroundColor`? You need to be setting `this.state.backgroundColor` from the beginning!

Sidenote: You should honestly rename `this.state.color` to something like `this.state.colorLabel`, or better, `this.state.headingLabel` or something. It is just for the label, not the color. Therefore, calling it `color` results in confusion, as can be seen in some of the other answers.

So you want:

```
changeColor(event) {
    var colorInput = document.getElementById('colorInput').value;
    this.setState({
      color: event.target.value,
      backgroundColor: event.target.value
    });
    if (colorInput === '') {
      this.setState({
        color: "Let's pick a color",
        backgroundColor: "#fff"
      });
    }
  }
```

And

```
render () {
    var styleObj = {
      backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor,
    };

    return (
      <section style={styleObj} id="Profile" >
        <h2 className="colorHeader">{this.state.color}</h2> 
        <input id="colorInput" placeholder="Enter Hex Code Here" onChange={this.changeColor.bind(this)}/>
      </section>
    );
  }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qdeodv?editors=0010

There's even better ways to refactor this, but this is just the basic resolution.

Comment: Ok I see what I did wrong - I basically needed to split the text and the background color into two separate values. So react state data types aren't strict then if I can pass a string? I was surprised to see that not break.

Comment: @kawnah, they're not strict if you can pass a string where? React data types aren't really strict though, I mean React is just javascript. So the data types (as far as `state` and variables go) will be as loose as those of Javascript.